# Why compilation stderr of C contains pwd of developers of static library I'm using?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to use 
[liboidc-agent (Github)](https://github.com/indigo-dc/oidc-agent/releases)
Which is compiled static library.

I think it is wrongly compiled because when I try to compile my program and link the library, see log below.

Note: /home/gabriel/Dokumente/... is not my directory. But most likely directory of developer. It shouldn't be there, right? Libraries should be reusable packages of code.

How to fix this and make liboidc-agent usable?
[Minimal example (Github)](https://github.com/ondrejvelisek/oidc-agent-lib-minimal-use)
Just run 'make'

Or am I missing something? 
Thank you for help!

```
make
gcc -o main main.c -L. -I. -loidc-agent
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o): In function `oidc_serror':
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/oidc_error.h:95: undefined reference to `oidc_sprintf'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/oidc_error.h:97: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o): In function `getAccountRequest':
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:12: undefined reference to `oidc_sprintf'
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o): In function `getAccessTokenRequest':
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:16: undefined reference to `isValid'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:19: undefined reference to `oidc_sprintf'
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o): In function `communicate':
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:27: undefined reference to `ipc_init'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:30: undefined reference to `ipc_connect'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:33: undefined reference to `ipc_vwrite'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:34: undefined reference to `ipc_read'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:35: undefined reference to `ipc_close'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:37: undefined reference to `printError'
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o): In function `getAccessToken':
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:58: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:66: undefined reference to `getJSONValues'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:67: undefined reference to `printError'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:68: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:71: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:75: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:76: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:77: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o):/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:80: more undefined references to `clearFreeString' follow
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o): In function `getLoadedAccounts':
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:103: undefined reference to `getJSONValues'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:104: undefined reference to `printError'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:105: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:108: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:112: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:113: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:114: undefined reference to `clearFreeString'
./liboidc-agent.a(api.o):/home/gabriel/Dokumente/git-repo/oidc-agent/src/api.c:117: more undefined references to `clearFreeString' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.a` file is just an archive containing several `.o` files bundled together, along with an optional symbol index. And an `.o` file does reference the source file so that the error is more precise - otherwise you'd just get an error from `api.o` instead of the actual source file where it comes from.

---

The real problem is that the *entire* `liboidc-agent.a` is just garbage. If you look into the file listing:

```
% ar t liboidc-agent.a 
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
api.o
```

instead of several different object files it has the *same* file all over in multiple copies. Nag with the user whose repository it is, get the library from another place or build it from source yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Because of this answer I looked in library makefile and find out there was several misakes. 

1/ It was archived with 'q' options which means add file (instead of 'r' as replace) => multiple files 

2/ 's' options was missing (for handling object files) 

3/ many object files was missing. If I understood correctly one source+header file means one object file. And then I have to compile all of them because gcc is not that 'smart' to collect all the tree by #include directive. resp. compiler includes header files (api) but not actual implementation. Its job for linker.

Answer (score 0):

So a library is simply a collection of the compiled object files. The developers of this library have shipped it with full pathnames to their working directories, which is an option that allows multiple object files with the same filename to live in the same library.

And I notice these are header files. GCC always includes the full path name for includes, so you know which setup.h file it has chosen, for example.

It would be much better if they streamlined their release process so the path name included the library name, at least!